# SVN out of date error

Tags: svn, merge, commit

I had a problem in one of my projects, I decided to checkout an older revision and do a few modifications to it. I am now trying to commit this older modified revision and any contained changes to HEAD.

When I do the svn ci -m "reverting with some changes" it gives me:

svn: File '/trunk/main.c' is out of date

I tried doing an update answering mine-conflict when prompted but it broke some other changed files.

Is there a way to commit my modified version to HEAD?

Thanks

Comment: Checkout HEAD. copy changed files into checkedout HEAD. commit HEAD.

Comment: Quick and dirty, it worked well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't check out an older revision, then commit it to the HEAD.  That wouldn't really make sense.  The order of steps should be: 1) check out old revision, 2) make changes, 3) update to current revision (merge), and 4) resolve conflicts.  It sounds like you're at step 4.

Comment: "That wouldn't really make sense." - actually that's precisely how MediaWiki handles reversions. ("You are editing an old revision of this page. If you save it, any changes made since then will be removed.")

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `svn st` to get a list of files that you modified
2. Save those files somewhere or, even better, checkout head in a different place
3. Merge the changes
4. Commit.